# Pass variable to callback

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, offlineapps

I'm building an app with offline functionality and am working with with WebSQL (I know it's deprecated, but it's what comes with PhoneGap)

I want to create an SQL find function that parses results and then calls a function that I'm passing to the `findAll` function. 
This is coffeescript, but I can translate into Javascript if that will get me an answer!

```
class window.TimeTravelDB

  findAll: (tableName, callback) ->
    @db.transaction (tx) ->
      tx.executeSql("Select * from #{tableName}", [], @db.querySuccess, @db.onError)

  querySuccess: (tx, results) ->
    rows = results.rows
    results = (JSON.parse(rows.item(i).data) for i in [0...rows.length])
    callback(results)
    return @results
```

How can I specify the callback for the `querySuccess` function in the `findAll` function?

Comment: `->` is a `function() { }` in CoffeeScript ?

Comment: yeah, it interprets to `findAll: function (tableName, callback) { return this.db.transaction(function (tx) {etc etc etc...`

Comment: @mu Thanks, I've been meaning to give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an intermediate callback rather than going directly to `querySuccess`, with `=>` to keep context for `@db`:

```
(tx, results) => @db.querySuccess(tx, results, callback)
```

This will allow it to forward on the `callback` passed to `findAll`:

```
findAll: (tableName, callback) ->
  @db.transaction (tx) ->
    tx.executeSql("Select * from #{tableName}", [],
      (tx, results) => @db.querySuccess(tx, results, callback),
      @db.onError
    )
```

Then adjust `querySuccess` for the argument:

```
querySuccess: (tx, results, callback = ->) ->
  # ...
```